# Robocopy copia interrumpida, ¿empezar desde el ultimo elemento que copia?

Tags: windows, consola, cmd

Tengo una lista de carpetas con subcarpetas muy grande, aproximadamente de 1 TB, estoy haciendo una copia de todos los datos con robocopy y la consola de windows.

La conexion al equipo es muy inestable, y a veces se queda colgado la consola y me obliga a lanzar el comando de robocopy otra vez.

¿Existe alguna manera de indicar a robocopy que empiece por donde se quedo la última vez? ¿Incluso decirle yo que empiece a partir de una carpeta?

Answer (score 0):

Según una búsqueda rápida en google, esto no se hace de forma nativa en Windows como si se hace en linux, puedes intentar dos cosas

1.- generar un [script VB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19093411/3486492) subir el script al equipo al que te conectas, ejecutarlo y luego cerrar la conexión

2.- Lo otro es usar el comando [START](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) propio de CMD (cmd, no windows) esto hará que se inicie otra instancia aparte de CMD

bueno, esto lo indico en base a supuestos, ya que en realidad nunca me he visto en la necesidad de hacer algo como esto, solo en escritorio remoto o en linux agregando un <kbd>&</kbd> para dejar el proceso corriendo de fondo, aunque con esto igual queda "pegado" a la terminal en ejecución con el comando `$ jobs` puedes mirar los procesos que están pegados a la terminal y luego con `$ disown %X` dejas el comando corriendo en memoria sin depender de la terminal en la que se está ejecutando la <kbd>X</kbd> representa el número de trabajo que devuelve el comando `jobs`. olvidé mencionar otro comando en linux `$ nohup "comando" &` con esto no es necesario ni listar con `jobs` ni nada

Espero te ayuden los puntos 1 y 2